# unable to debug one js file, other working

Tags: javascript

suddenly debugging for one js file in VS studio 2013 stops working. When I set break-point, it gets message, that no symbols have been loaded.
In solution explorer in Script Documents, the js file is shown as "eval code" file, when other js files are normally *.js.
Tried to debug via browser, but the js file is not loaded into the files, which can be debugged in the browser.
Spend already 4 hours to fix this, tried several solutions found on net, but no success.
edit: the debugger key word in js file worked, this can be used as workaround.

Comment: Since you not providing source code, did you tried this: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/6dddb105-066a-4583-a1bd-9bc7f5719516/debugging-causes-vs-to-create-eval-code-files?forum=vsdebug

Comment: Did you re-start the debugging session / Visual Studio yet?

Comment: I tryied: enable/disable deubugging in ie, just my code in VS, restarting PC, silverlight debugging. The main problem is, that only one of many js files in project does not hit breakpoint in debug (and this one appears as eval code -> thought this is usefull info for somebody). I am debugging the other js files just fine in VS.